# What's the youngest age when someone joined a political party in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, parties, demographics

[Apparently](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-47907350)

> Annunziata Rees-Mogg joined the Conservative Party, at the age of five, in 1984.

So is this a record, or are are even younger examples?

Comment: Children under 15 can only join, or belong to, the UK Conservative Party as non-voting members.